# Double Quotes on VarNames Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am reading a comma-separated text file into Matlab with the dataset() function. The variable names in the text file contain double quotes around the names. I am reading this file into Matlab, manipulating the data, and exporting to a separate text file. The issue is that I need the double quotes to remain around the variable names; however, Matlab removes them. 
Is there a way I can tell Matlab to keep the quotes, or an easy way to replace the quotes before exporting? Thanks

Text file looks like this: ["Var1","Var2",....] - There is no issue with Matlab importing the file.

```
    inputname = 'MyFile.TXT';
    outputname = 'MyOutput.TXT';
    rawinventory = dataset('File', inputname', 'Delimiter', ',', 
    'ReadVarNames', true); 
    rawinventory(1,1); %The Command Window shows the first entry and the 
    %header name without the double quotes.

    temp_raw = dataset2cell(rawinventory(:,:));

    % Perform some data Manipulation here
    %........

    edited_raw = cell2dataset(temp_raw(:,:));
    export(edited_raw, 'File', outputname, 'Delimiter', ',');
```

I know that there may be better ways to run this code. My job is not as a developer or IT. I occasionally need to edit files used in other processes. Unfortunately, the process after this manipulation requires the double quotes around the variable names.

Comment: You can't achieve this by using datasets since row names cannot contain double quotes...

Comment: Tommaso Belluzzo - Do you have any suggestions on what type of object will work? Thanks

Comment: Direct text writing and cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function solves this issue. Place the .m file for the function in the same folder as the .m file with the code.  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25387-write-cell-array-to-text-file?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

```
inputname = 'MyFile.TXT';
outputname = 'MyOutput.TXT';
rawinventory = dataset('File', inputname', 'Delimiter', ',', 
'ReadVarNames', true); 
rawinventory(1,1); %The Command Window shows the first entry and the 
%header name without the double quotes.

temp_raw = dataset2cell(rawinventory(:,:));

for y = 1:size(temp_raw,2);
    temp_raw(1,y) = strcat('"',temp_raw(1,y),'"');
end %This for loop replaces the double quotes

% Perform some data Manipulation here
%........

dlmcell(outputname,temp_raw,',');
```